# How to find similar strings inside Array with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have info like this inside an array-

```
{codigo: "", clave: "USB005", nombre: "memoria usb kingston 16 GB", precio: "165", stock: "0"}

{codigo: "", clave: "USB001", nombre: "MEMORIA USB BLACKPCS 16 GB", precio: "165", stock: "0"}

{codigo: "", clave: "USB003", nombre: "MEMORIA USB SP 16 GB", precio: "165", stock: "0"}
```

And I have a textfield for searching specific data, for now it works with the key `codigo` and `clave` but I would like to make it work with `nombre` as well but in this case is different because if I write "Memoria" it should get the values the matches the word but I have no idea how to achieve this, I tried with `indexOf` but it doesn't work as I thought

This is how I did with `codigo` and `clave`

```
$.each(todos, function(i) {

    if (busqueda == todos[i]['clave'] || busqueda == todos[i]['codigo']) {

        $('#resultado_precio').html(
            `<h4 class="text-danger m-t-25"><b>Precio: $ ${decimales(todos[i]['precio'])}</b></h4>
            <h4 class="text-danger"><b>${todos[i]['nombre']}</b></h4>
            <h4 class="text-danger"><b>Stock: ${todos[i]['stock']}</b></h4>`
        );

        return;

 }
```

});

How can make to find the first 5 matches of the word I write to search in the key `nombre`?

I hope you can help me with some ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use `indexOf()` with OR (`||`) condition like below:-***

***Working example:-***

```js
var todos = [{codigo: "", clave: "USB005", nombre: "memoria usb kingston 16 GB", precio: "165", stock: "0"},{codigo: "", clave: "USB001", nombre: "MEMORIA USB BLACKPCS 16 GB", precio: "165", stock: "0"},{codigo: "", clave: "USB003", nombre: "MEMORIA USB SP 16 GB", precio: "165", stock: "0"}];

var busqueda = "memoria";
$.each(todos, function(i) {

  if (busqueda == todos[i]['clave'] || busqueda == todos[i]['codigo'] || todos[i]['nombre'].toUpperCase().indexOf(busqueda.toUpperCase()) !==-1) {

    alert('found');

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note:- you can use `toLowerCase()` also

Comment: Accidently deleted the comment. All good man!!

Comment: Thank you, in this way now I can see a way to solve my problem

Comment: @Ashe  glad to help you.:):)